# how to replace all column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[![I want to replace File_attribute and region
_attribute column value with '{}'][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp1wj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp1wj.jpg)

Comment: Hi, can you please post the data as text? and the requirement too? check how here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples-

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is in a Pandas DataFrame object `df`,

```
df['File_attribute'] = '{}'
df['Region_attribute'] = '{}'
```